# how to mock axios of apisauce

Tags: react-testing-library, babel-jest

Trying to mock an API call which accessed by apisauce.

basically API below retrieve list of some object, and I need to test this api call via jest

here what I tried;

TagApi:

```
import { ApiResponse, ApisauceInstance } from 'apisauce'
import { Instance } from 'mobx-state-tree'

export const TagApi = {
  apisauce: {} as ApisauceInstance,
  getUserTags: async (userId: number) => {
    const response: ApiResponse<Array<Instance<typeof UserTag>>> = await TagApi.apisauce.get(
      `/users/${userId}/tags/`,
    )

    return handleResponse(response)
  },
}
```

users-tab.test.ts:

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'
import { TagApi } from '@/core/src/services/api-objects/TagApi'

import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter'

test('mock adapter', async () => {
  const mock = new MockAdapter(TagApi.apisauce.axiosInstance)
  mock.onGet('/users/2/tags/').reply(201, {
    x: 'hello',
  })
  const response = await TagApi.getUserTags(2)
  expect(response.ok).toBe(true)
  expect(response.status).toBe(201)
  expect(response.data).toEqual({ x: 'hello' })
})
```

I expect it to run, but it fails exception with the message:
[image]

how to fix it?

Comment: The error message is clear. Your `TagApi.apisauce` is an empty object. There is no `axiosInstance`